# Internet showing in visible networks but not connecting

Tags: networking, network-manager, bluetooth, internet

I have Ubuntu (20.04) and I am typing this from another device.(Proving that internet is working on all my devices except on ubuntu). I have no coding experience per say but I have used the terminal once or twice not successfully might I add. The internet sometimes connects of it's own free will but since restarting the internet won't connect. I can see the connection in visible networks but it is not connecting. The bluetooth is also not working saying that a dongle is needed to turn it on. Yesterday when I tried connecting to the net I saw the brief message of "secrets required but not found' or something.
Could someone please help me fix this issue
I have tried a multitude of things including restarting network manager and whatnot
I would be eternally grateful if someone could help

Comment: How are you connecting? 802.11 (Wi-Fi) networks generally require password, and most desktops and laptops can't connect to mobile networks.

Comment: Forgive me if I misunderstood your question but I have a wireless connection (I don't know how to connect to wifi with ethernet cable). The password and everything is there but when i try to connect it shows that it's connecting and then just doesn't connect

Comment: Please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and edit the question to include results from the wireless script